# Why extra_kwargs is used if it can be replaced?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am writing a project using django-rest-framework and while using serializers, I realized that most of the keywords in extra_kwargs like "required, read_only, write_only, etc." can be substituted by read_only_fields, write_only_fields, "required" in serializer fields, etc. Does extra_kwargs have some feature that is unique?

Comment: You do not need to specify the type of the field, since that is determined by the model. Often you want to avoid specifying the type of the field, since it is possible that you later change the type of the field in the modeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partly answered in the [documentation on `extra_kwargs` [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments):

> Please keep in mind that, if the **field has already been explicitly declared** on the serializer class, then the `extra_kwargs` option will be ignored.

If you thus do not specify the items in the `extra_kwargs`, you need to specify the field itself, so for example:

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializer.CharField(write_only=True)
```

But imagine that you later change your mind, and you want to work with an `IntegerField` for the password, then you will not only need to change the model field, but also serializer field(s) that work with that password. So then `MyUserSerializer` looks like:

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializer.IntegerField(write_only=True)
```

By working with `extra_kwargs`, you do not specify the field itself, and you can simply "inject" parameters with `extra_kwargs` into that field.

Answer (score 1):

when you set `read_only` or `write_only` or etc. in `kwargs` you specified them to the field of the model (*it will have the model field validation plus your validations*)

but when you overwrite the field in the serializer, *it won't have the model field validations* anymore (like unique, unique together or etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use validator for extra_kwargs:

```
'email': {
            'validators': [
                UniqueValidator(
                    queryset=User.objects.all()
                )
            ]
        }
```